# disable the validation when input text is blank

Tags: jsf-2

I want to disable the validation when user did not enter the text.I am trying to chech whether the input text is empty. plz suggest hot to check empty for text box.

```
<h:inputText  value="#{countryBean.usersDetailsDTO.firstName}" id="empFName" disabled="#{not(countryBean.selectedEid eq '1')}">
        <f:validator  validatorId="nameValidation" disabled="#{empty countryBean.usersDetailsDTO.firstName}"/>
        </h:inputText>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, using the disabled attribute in this way would not work as intended because the value of the firstName attribute would be set in the Update Model Values phase, while validation will occur prior to that in the Process Validations phase.  I would expect it to disable the validator only if the firstName field were already set to null/empty on the prior request.

As for how to accomplish the task.  Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/6113982/2725716