# Myfaces 2.0.5 : Disable validation if no value entered in field

Tags: jsf, weblogic-10.x, myfaces, jboss-eap-7

Currently we are moving application from Weblogic 11g to Jboss eap 7.

For JSF forms, custom validator is enabled in this application as below

```
<h:inputText id="lastName" maxlength="30" styleClass="InputBoxMedium" value="#{searchBean.lastName}" onkeyup="checkAllEmptyField('Search', 'searchActive', 'searchInactive', 5)">
                                        <f:validator validatorId = "searchValidator"/>
                                    </h:inputText>
```

Assume we have 10 similar fields, 
In Weblogic, this validator is only called for validation for non-empty fields
In Jboss, validator is called for all fields.

we would like to have weblogic behavior in jboss.

Comment: Tried playing with null vs empty in jsf input fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding following in web.xml helped to resolve the problem in Jboss eap 7.....hope this will help someone in future....

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.VALIDATE_EMPTY_FIELDS</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Not sure why this was not required in weblogic :-(

below link helped me, pls check it for details
[Shouldn't the validation be skipped when there is no value specified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6113935/shouldnt-the-validation-be-skipped-when-there-is-no-value-specified)

Comment: Wired part is without this context-param, application is skipping validation for empty fields in weblogic.....anyway adding this in jboss code version solved the problem